# Calling a JavaScript function linked to my project using ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to call a JavaScript function which is linked to my project. This function has 3 parameters. I'm using this parameters from an array on a ng-repeat. 
If I use onclick event with 3 predefined parameter the function is executed with no problem. However, if I try to pass the parameters on the onclick function using `{{a.param}}`, it doesn't work.
If I try to use ng-click using the function and passing the parameters using `{{a.param}}` or `a.param` also does not work.
Can I call my JavaScript function from scope? I cannot define the JavaScript function on scope as I have seen in many articles.

Comment: can you post a plunk?

Comment: Please provide the relevant code. We can't help you with what we can't see

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

```js
(function(){
  var app = angular.module("app",[]);
  
  var module = angular.module("app");
  
  module.controller("controller", function(){
    var model=this;
    model.param1="not initialized";
    model.param2="not initialized";
    
    model.param3="not initialized";
    
    model.doWork = function(param1,param2,param3)
    {
      model.param1=param1;
      model.param2=param2;
      model.param3=param3;
    };
  });
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controller as model">
      {{model.param1}}
      <br/>
      {{model.param2}}
      <br/>
      {{model.param3}}
      
      <input type="button" value="Click" ng-click='model.doWork("this is param1",model.param2,"Some random string")')> 
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope it helps!